# CPU or RAM in game development?

Tags: java, memory, cpu

I'm beginning to work on a game server written in Java. Granted, Java is not the best solution to server development, but it is the language that I am most comfortable with.

I'm trying to design this game server to handle a lot of connections, and I'm not sure what to focus more on: storing data in memory or keeping memory usage down and using more raw CPU power?

Comment: This is a pretty generic question, so here's a generic answer: Use as much memory as viable and sacrifice time to handle amounts of data that require more memory.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?  Unless that's your goal of course :)  Check out the successor to Project Darkstar, [RedDwarf Server](http://www.reddwarfserver.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly depends on what your game is like.  I recently benchmarked my server with 5,000 clients at like 20MB of ram.  You may keep much more state data than me, and it could be a concern.

Your serious issue with many connections is setting up the sockets to handle it properly, using certain manner of socket handling becomes very bogged down or breaks @1024 connections etc.  I'm not sure how much optimization you can do in java.

Look at [this link](http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent/) for what I'm talking about.

And, good luck!  And also, switch languages as soon as possible to a language offering comparable features to java but without the awful drawbacks (meaning Objective-C or C#).  I'm not just "slamming java" but the problem you're going to reach when you talk about doing things that are performant is that java will abstract you too far from the Operating System and you will not be able to take advantage of optimizations when you need it.

Comment: thanks, I appreciate your response! I'm using a library called KryoNet (http://code.google.com/p/kryonet/) for socket management, which is highly optimized and created mainly for Java game development. I will switch out of Java as soon as possible, as you recommended.

Comment: There are ways to use Java and still get the OS optimizations.  You could encapsulate the heavy lifting in native libraries and call them using JNI.

Comment: @Abrupt one explanation to back up my suggestion is that I wrote my game engine in one language (C++) and decided to rewrite it in another language (Objective-C) when it was ~50% done.  Let me say that it took me *far* longer than I expected to accomplish this. My lesson was definitely "start as you mean to go" - if there's another language you'd like to learn, this will be a great way to get hands on with that language. If you expect you're going to rewrite later, you could be really creating a mess for yourself.  Good luck to you

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest you design the server for far more than you really need to.  If you suddenly find you have 10,000s of clients, you can re-design the system.

I would start with a basic server e.g. i5 with 8 GB of memory for less than £500, or an i7 with 24 GB for less than £1000.

As your number of connections grows you are likely to run out of bandwidth before you run out of resources unless you use a cloud solution.

BTW: You can implement a high frequency trading system with less than 100 micro-second latency in Java.  I haven't heard of any Objective-C high frequency trading systems.  C# might be able to perform as well or better on Windows, but I prefer Linux for server system.